# Codec and format problems with DLNA Server

Tags: windows, codec, mpeg, media-server, dlna

I use the Windows build in DLNA server controlled with the Windows Media Player under Windows Vista. This is working. The problem is that the Sony Bravia TV does not list all videos which I have share. After comparing the listing videos and the not listing videos the difference are the file format and the codec. The TV show only videos in in mpeg format and with a Nero codec. AVI and WMV are not show. And also no mpeg file with another codec.

What is the simplest solution to solve this? Are there DLNA server software for Windows that can convert it on the fly? I think it will not be possible to install any codec in the TV.

Answer (score 1):

PS3MediaServer is exactly what you want: "DLNA server software for Windows that can convert it on the fly"

Beware that for high quality high definition on-the-fly transcoding you will need a good cpu (like core 2 duo).